# Import node.js module into docpad

Tags: node.js, module, docpad

I just started learning Node.js and created some modules to retrieve data from some APIs. I would like to create a website where I combine all these data and discovered docpad, which, by the way, seems really nice.
The problem is that I can't find out to import my modules.

I have tried following the guide on docpads website with copying the modules to the folder */plugins*. Then creating a coffee script to load them in */src/mypluginfilename.plugin.coffee*.

```
module.exports = (BasePlugin) ->
# Define Plugin
class mypluginfilenamePlugin extends BasePlugin
    # Plugin name
    name: 'mypluginfilename'
```

In my */src/documents/scripts/script.js* it throws me an error when I try to use the module.

```
var mymodule = require('mypluginfilename.js');
```

I hope you can help me out here guys. I think this is simple, but that I screwed it up :P

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are after [browserify](http://browserify.org/)...